# Sum of Hours, Minutes and Seconds across same Id - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, sum

I have a table which only which stores the login and logout date against a user along with their time and their datatype is `datetime`.

The dates are stored in the format `2021-12-17 14:05:25.597`.

I am able to get the total time duration between the login and logout date but I need to sum all the rows across a particular user against a date.

Here is some sample data:

```
 Sno      USERID  Name    LoginDateAndTime       LogOutDateAndTime     TimeDuration   Total
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1       222    abc     17 Dec 2021 1:40PM     17 Dec 2021 1:40PM     0:0:9         
   2       222    abc     17 Dec 2021 2:05PM     17 Dec 2021 3:07PM     1:2:4
   3       444    xyz     18 Dec 2021 3:37PM     18 Dec 2021 3:37PM     0:0:6
   4       444    xyz     16 Dec 2021 1:51PM     16 Dec 2021 2:22PM     0:30:24
   5       444    xyz     16 Dec 2021 10:17PM    16 Dec 2021 10:18PM    0:1:20
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    u.userid, u.Name,
    CONVERT(varchar, la.loginDate, 106) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), la.loginDate, 100), 7)) AS LoginDateAndTime,
    CONVERT(varchar, la.logoutDate,106) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), la.logoutDate, 100), 7)) AS LogOutDateAndTime,
    CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate) / 3600) + ':' + 
       CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate) % 3600 / 60) + ':' + 
       CONVERT(varchar(5), (DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate) % 60)) AS 'TimeDuration',
FROM
    login la
LEFT JOIN
    users u ON u.userid = la.id
```

Now I want to show a new column that sums up the hours and minutes across same Ids and same date.

I did multiple searches but I am still confused.

For example:

- Against `Id = 222` there are two entries with same date so the total would be  `0:0:9` plus `1:2:4` which is `1:2:13`
- Against `Id = 444` there are three entries with two different dates so against Sno `3` The total would be same that is  `0:0:6` and
  against Sno `4` and `5` these two would add i.e `0:30:24` and `0:1:20` .

How can I achieve this?Anyone can help me with this? Its quite complicated

Comment: What's wrong with just `SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate))`

Comment: @Charlieface I need to get the sum of hours minutes seconds across same Id's and same date. ``SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate))`` wont do the job

Comment: Just choose your grouping `GROUP BY UserId, CAST(loginDate AS date)`

Comment: @Charlieface Can you maybe edit my query? That would really help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to group by user ID and date.

> It's unclear why you have a `LEFT JOIN` here, why isn't it an `INNER`

```sql
SELECT
    times.userid,
    times.Name,
    times.LoginDate,
    CONVERT(varchar(5), TotalDurationS / 3600) + ':' + 
       CONVERT(varchar(5), TotalDurationS % 3600 / 60) + ':' + 
       CONVERT(varchar(5), TotalDurationS % 60) AS TotalDuration
FROM
(
    SELECT
      u.userid,
      u.Name,
      CAST(la.loginDate AS date) AS LoginDate,
      SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate)) AS TotalDurationS
    FROM login la
    JOIN users u ON u.userid = la.id
    GROUP BY
      u.userid,
      u.Name,
      CAST(la.loginDate AS date)
) times;
```

- We begin by grouping by `userid` and the date (which we get by casting `as date`)
- Then we get the `SUM` of the `DATEDIFF` calculation
- We then format it as a time

Comment: Your query is giving me errors. ``Incorrect syntax near times`` Also can you explain what this does?

Comment: Sorry missing `FROM`

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. as this query is giving me strange results and not my desired result .

Comment: Looks right to me given your sample data, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28cd18064d06e1ba12e6fb4ec362d546

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using the sub query? @Charlieface

Comment: Yes, I just find it more long-winded https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77a150a915ce38898bffa217f0c9fa2d

Comment: You created a table and inserted all the data into it. How even, in my query I am getting the time duration using my dates column i.e login and logout date. So I am having a hard time adjusting it into my query

Comment: Without a [mcve] containing `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements (you can do this in https://dbfiddle.uk), I can't really help you further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240268/discussion-between-unknown-and-charlieface).

Answer (score 1):

based on your fiddles, i also created one, but currently im unable to comment, so posted it as an answer:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3980a6b2eec812d82fe9ed43339981c2

```
--with-clause begins
--pre as (...) is the first query within the with-clause
with pre as (
    select
        USERID,
        Name,
        CAST(loginDate AS date) AS LoginData,
        convert(varchar,loginDate,106) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),loginDate, 100), 7)) as LoginDateAndTime,
        convert(varchar,logoutDate,106) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),logoutDate, 100), 7)) as LogOutDateAndTime,
        convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, loginDate, logoutDate)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, loginDate, logoutDate)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, loginDate, logoutDate)%60)) as 'Time Duration Of Login [hh:mm:ss]'
    from
        login
),
--total as (...) is the second query within the with-clause
total as (
    SELECT
        userid,
        Name,
        CAST(loginDate AS date) AS LoginData,
        CONVERT(varchar(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate)) / 3600) + ':' + 
        CONVERT(varchar(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate)) % 3600 / 60) + ':' + 
        CONVERT(varchar(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate)) % 60) AS TotalDuration
    FROM
        login
    GROUP BY
        userid,
        Name,
        CAST(loginDate AS date)
)
--with-clause ends
select
    pre.*,
    total.totalduration
    from
        pre
    join
        total 
    on
        pre.userid = total.userid
        and total.LoginData = pre.loginData
```

please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 for detailed explanation

in short words, `with`-clauses are used to organize and simplyfy complex sql-statements, for example: to get rid of sub-queries with `select`-statements; so `with`-clauses 'make sql-statements easier to read'

therefore the `with`-clause provides one ore more temporary named resultset(s), also known as common table expression (CTE), that are defined within the execution scope of a single `select`, `insert`, `update`, `delete` or `merge` statement

in my posted statement, i combined your query (pre) and @Charlieface s query (total)

@Charlieface s query (total) `sum`s up the loginduration for each userid, name and logindate.

if i got you right, you wanted to achieve a query, that returns all rows from login-table expanded by the total login-duration per date and per user (id and name)

thats what the statement above does.

if i got you wrong and you want to achieve a query that return all rows from login-table expanded by the total login-duration overall dates per user (id and name), i customized the statement as follows, my customization - in relation to the statement above - are the commented lines within the statement:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2240f4ce7364ceccbcc8eec88dfada6

```
with pre as (
    select
        USERID,
        Name,
        --CAST(loginDate AS date) AS LoginData,
        convert(varchar,loginDate,106) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),loginDate, 100), 7)) as LoginDateAndTime,
        convert(varchar,logoutDate,106) + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),logoutDate, 100), 7)) as LogOutDateAndTime,
        convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, loginDate, logoutDate)/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, loginDate, logoutDate)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, loginDate, logoutDate)%60)) as 'Time Duration Of Login [hh:mm:ss]'
    from
        login
),
total as (
    SELECT
        userid,
        Name,
        --CAST(loginDate AS date) AS LoginData,
        CONVERT(varchar(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate)) / 3600) + ':' + 
        CONVERT(varchar(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate)) % 3600 / 60) + ':' + 
        CONVERT(varchar(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(s, loginDate, logoutDate)) % 60) AS TotalDuration
    FROM
        login
    GROUP BY
        userid,
        Name
        --,
        --CAST(loginDate AS date)
)
select
    pre.*,
    total.totalduration
    from
        pre
    join
        total 
    on
        pre.userid = total.userid
        --and total.LoginData = pre.loginData
```

Comment: Let me try if this works!!

Comment: Hi can you explain this query? Also this query is not showing the correct sum in seconds in total duration column

Comment: Hi. Your query is fine but what if I want to get total duration based on the results my query returns. Right now, it returns all rows from login-table expanded by the total login-duration per date and per user (id and name). In my sample data, for eg if my query retunrs Sno 5 then the total would show for both Sno 4 and 5. Since they are of same date. But what If i want to show total duration based on my query results?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer was at first comments of @Charlieface, after adding a conversion from seconds to H:M:S like `dateAdd(ss, yourTotalSeconds, 0)`, and finally converting to `time(0)`

Sample data:

```
declare @tb table (
      Sno int not null identity
    , userid int not null
    , name varchar(30)
    , loginDate datetime
    , logoutDate datetime)
insert @tb values
(222, 'abc', '20211217 13:40:10', '20211217 13:40:19'),
(222, 'abc', '20211217 14:05:20', '20211217 15:07:24'),
(444, 'xyz', '20211218 15:37:30', '20211218 15:37:36'),
(444, 'xyz', '20211216 13:51:40', '20211218 14:22:04'),
(444, 'xyz', '20211216 22:17:30', '20211218 22:18:50')
```

Solution:

```
;with CTE as (
select userid
    , cast(loginDate as date) DateLogged
    , cast(dateAdd(ss, sum(dateDiff(ss, loginDate, logoutDate)), 0) as time(0)) TimeLogged
from @tb
group by userid, cast(loginDate as date))
select t.*
    , cast(logoutDate - loginDate as time(0)) TimeDuration
    , TimeLogged Total
from @tb t
join CTE c on (t.userid = c.userid and cast(t.loginDate as date) = c.DateLogged)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1709376a65ecbb2c60daec0f19c4d565)